# Logic Apps get scope status and use in a condition

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Im having a workflow inside a scope and i want to do a condition after the scope which checks the status of the scope. By my understanding every step in a workflow have some outputs which contains the status, Succeeded, Skipped or Failed.
My logic apps Scope output:

```
{
    "name": "Scope",
    "startTime": "2017-02-06T14:48:45.4586635Z",
    "endTime": "2017-02-06T14:48:46.5367815Z",
    "trackingId": "XXX,
    "clientTrackingId": "XXX",
    "status": "Succeeded"
}
```

I have tried a similar solution with actions but with the outsputs.statusCode, i have a working condition that looks like:

```
"@equals(actions('Get_Blob_Metadata_using_path').outputs.statusCode, 200)",
```

But was wondering if its possible to get the "status" from the workflow and use it in the condition.

Comment: _possible to get the "status" from the workflow and use it in the condition_ In case of nested workflow scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** Run-after configuration is not available in designer. Click "..." of any card that's not a trigger or first action, and you will be able to change the condition it runs after without having to switch to code view.

---

It would be great if you can describe the scenario so I can provide more specific advise, but based on your description, you may not need condition.

If you switch to code view, you will see "Run-after" property for each action, within it, there's run-after condition, and run after action.

If you add an action (let's call it action1) after the scope in designer, you will see the new action will by default, run after the scope action succeed. Now add another action (let's call it action2) at the end, but modify it's run-after to be after the scope action has failed or skipped.

Now, depending on the scope's status, either action1 or action2 will run, but never both.

Comment: It worked since i didnt notice the run-after condition, only saw run-after action.

Comment: We have to plan to make  it easier to modify the run-after condition from designer view, stay tuned. :)